# Spring release system 2.1m long rocket with a weight of 20kg

Tags: amateur-rocketry, recovery, parachute

We have been searching for a trustworthy source to help us design the recovery sytem for a rocket which is going to fly 2600m high with a weight of 22.6kg in the beginning and 17kg in the end (at the descent). We have been searching for a way to calculate how many newtons our spring system should output in orde to deploy the parachute (together with a pneumatic system). Can somebody help us determining what sort of springs we should use?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the relevance of the rocket's mass? The parachute's mass is what you're trying to move, right?  Also you've tagged this 'rocketlab', can you explain the connection?

Comment: The weight of the parachute will be around 1.2kg to 1.5kg, we don't know it exactly yet since the design isn't fully finished. We are trying to move the parachute but also the nose cone above the parachute (which is held in place with the pneumatic system). I tagged rocketlab but I don't know what it is... I just thought it would cover all of the design components of the rocket.

Comment: @IngmarPrins Rocketlab is actually a space company which frequently launches their electron rocket and is now working on their Neutron rocket. It is one of the competitors of SpaceX. I think you might have thought that it meant a lab for rockets, but that tag is actually for questions related to the company.

Comment: Ow, sorry... I'm new to the platform and scene, thanks however for correcting! If you have any idea however how you could help with determining how many newtons our springs should ouput it is always appreciated!

Comment: There's way too many details you're eliding here. We don't know anything about the parachute or the pneumatic system. Fundamentally, you should turn to the physics, draw a free body diagram, figure out the forces involved, and then do some acceptance testing to see if your parachute will inflate.  I don't see how we can help you.  There certainly isn't going to be a single equation for this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a spring which, when pre-loaded, will store the impulse needed to impart a separation velocity “v” to two masses “M1” = rocket body mass and “M2”= parachute module mass.

We can use an inertial frame of reference which is “stationary” at the moment of triggering the spring mechanism and therefor momentum = zero.

[image]

Since momentum is conserved, momentum is still zero post release.

The individual momentum of M1 and M2 have changed but, since velocity of the two masses is in opposite directions, momentum is in opposite directions and cancels to zero. Note v1 + v2 = v (separation velocity).

To calculate the impulse needed to be supplied by the spring, you must provide both M1 and M2 as well as the desired separation velocity "v".

To calculate the spring design, standard text book spring equations can be used. Note that the spring rate of a spiral spring can be calculated from only the wire size and wire length, independent of spring diameter, pitch and number of coils. This makes it easy to pick spring dimensions which fit within the confines of your rocket design.